# Can't upload a file with Sahi / Mink / Behat in a Symfony2 application

Tags: php, symfony, behat, mink, sahi

I am using Mink and Sahi for my user interface tests inside a Symfony2 application. But actually I can't manage to upload a file with Sahi.

My Sahi server is up and running:

```
[09:51:33] coil@ubuntu:~/Webdev/sahi/bin$ ./sahi.sh 
--------
SAHI_HOME: ..
SAHI_USERDATA_DIR: ../userdata
SAHI_EXT_CLASS_PATH:
--------
Sahi properties file = /home/coil/Webdev/sahi/config/sahi.properties
Sahi user properties file = /home/coil/Webdev/sahi/userdata/config/userdata.properties
Added shutdown hook.
>>>> Sahi started. Listening on port: 9999
>>>> Configure your browser to use this server and port as its proxy
>>>> Browse any page and CTRL-ALT-DblClick on the page to bring up the Sahi Controller
-----
Reading browser types from: /home/coil/Webdev/sahi/userdata/config/browser_types.xml
-----
```

My step implementation:

```php
    // $element->getXpath() --> (//html/descendant-or-self::*[@id = 'attachment'])[1]
$element->attachFile($file);
```

Note here that if I use a file that is not `/home/coil/Webdev/sahi/userdata` directory, I get the following error:

```php
$element->attachFile('toto');
```

```bash
error:_setFile2(_byXPath("(//html/descendant-or-self::*[@id = 'attachment'])[1]"), "toto")
      Error: File not found: toto; Base directory is userdata directory: /home/coil/Webdev/sahi/userdata
      Error: File not found: toto; Base directory is userdata directory: /home/coil/Webdev/sahi/userdata
      at Sahi._setFile (http://dev.project.com/_s_/spr/concat.js:1398:12)
      at Sahi._setFile2 (http://dev.project.com/_s_/spr/concat.js:1367:7)
      at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://dev.project.com/_s_/spr/concat.js:3480:14), <anonymous>:1:7)
      at Sahi.ex (http://dev.project.com/_s_/spr/concat.js:3480:9)
      at <anonymous>:1:11
      <a href='/_s_/dyn/Log_getBrowserScript?href=null&n=-1'><b>Click for browser script</b></a>
```

So, Sahi can "find" the file as it doesn't raise any error with a valid and existing file. But when the form is submitted, the file is never uploaded by the Sahi proxy.

Other checks:

- I removed the client side HTML5 and JavaScript validation to be sure there is no side effect.
- All my other Sahi tests are Ok, only the 3 with an Upload don't pass
- The proxy is set in my testing browser
- I can open the Sahi controller in the browser without problem
- Same problem on MaxOsX and Ubuntu
- Each time I run an upload test, I've got a new entry in /userdata/temp/download named like `sahi_11a83f8806be8046fc0aaa80eac076110b95__fr-fr-2-0.bdic`

What is really weird, is that I am sure that those tests passed some times ago, something must have changed in my application or configuration that breaks the Sahi file upload but I can't find what.
And before in the Sahi console I had logs about the files that it was uploading, now there is no log at all.

Comment: Are you running the application in "dev" or in "production" environment? That may be the reason why you don't see any logs?

Comment: It uses the `test` environment. But I am talking about the Sahi logs not the application logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the url to which the form is posted different from the url of the web page? _setFile and _setFile2 take a third parameter which can be configured to point to the action URL (the url to which the file should be attached by the Sahi Proxy) http://sahi.co.in/w/_setFile

Comment: The form post in the same URL as the form itself: `<form id="apply" action="/app_test.php/postuler-1"
      method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">`

Comment: I also tried with `_setFile2` on the last version of Sahi, without success.

Answer (score 2):

Use absolute system path to which Sahi server has access.

Comment: I tried with `/tmp/file.doc` without success. I really feel that something is not well configured at the proxy level.

Comment: Might be. But I'm sure uploading works as SahiDriver test suite passes. And it has file upload test case :/

Comment: If you run only the upload test, do you have a log in the `/bin/sahi.sh` console showing what file is being uploaded ?